# IE textbox loses focus after DOM modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a search box(normal text box) that changes a HTML Table after each keypress.
On Chrome works well but on IE the input box loses focus whenever the html table changes.

I tried to set focus back by using the focus() method but that makes the cursor to go to the beggining of the textbox, and I don´t want to put the cursor to the end of the word in the textbox, I wanted or to prevent the lose of focus or make the cursor behave normally.

Eg. In case the user types 3 letters and he goes back one letter and type a new letter I don´t want the cursor go to the end of the word but to stay at the same position after the typing.

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: Are you sure? The code is kind big and I think I have explained it well. It´s well known that IE does weird stuff after DOM changes (like the table I´m modifying after keypress). IE´s inputs just loses focus after ANY DOM change and Chrome doesn´t. I just don´t want it to lose focus. Or set the focus back to the input in the previous position. Although I think a prevention of losing focus is a better approach in this case.

Comment: How is the DOM being changed? innerHTML, appendChild, removeChild. It makes a difference.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn´t know IE would account that. Well I´m just using jquery´s .hide() and .show() methods to show and hide table rows (<tr>). That´s the only DOM change I do after a keypress.